# CRON Job not executing Python script

Tags: python, cron

I created a CRON Job to run a Python script at 11.45 everyday. However, when I tested , I see that python script is not getting executed:

```
45 11 * * * /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/Documents/Example/main.py
```

I think that the problem is with python installation directory since I have multiple python installations and I am not sure which is correct one:

To check python installation, I used following command:

```
whereis python
```

Output:

```
python: /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.7 
/usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.6 
/etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 
/usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python 
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

I have added executable permissions to the Python script and its parent directory:

```
chmod a+x /home/user/Documents/Example/main.py
```

Note: I want to use python 2.7 for execution of the script. Is there anything that I am doing wrong

Comment: can you post the result of `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` ? Obviously remove private information, if any.

Comment: Have you tried running the command you added to cron i.e. does this execute `/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/Documents/Example/main.py` when you run it in your command line? Also to find full path of shell command use `which`, `whereis` is used to `locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command`

Comment: I think the correct path for python 2.7 is **/etc/python2.7**. Try executing the script before iinserting it on crontab. `/etc/python2.7 /home/user/Documents/Example/main.py`  or even `/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/Documents/Example/main.py` and post the output.

Comment: What is your script trying to do?, and how do you know that it is not executing?

Comment: No MTA installed, discarding output: This is the rror I get when it tries to execute the job @Miles Davis

Comment: @ bagljas . I did try this. It works fine for both the commands

Comment: @Tjs01 are you able to execute something simpler for example: `*/1 * * * * echo "testing" >> /tmp/test.txt` This will run every minute and append `testing` to `/tmp/test.txt` file (don't forget to remove this from your crontab after testing). If this works, problem might be with `main.py`.

Comment: Yes. I was able to run that. I tried creating a simple txt file initially. That's where I realized the problem was with Python

Comment: @Tjs01 can you post minimal `main.py` script which shows this issue, so we can reproduce the issue?